# Do ranged sneak attacks using bows or magic deal extra damage?

Tags: the-elder-scrolls-v-skyrim

Melee sneak attacks are supposed to deal *a lot* of extra damage, as I'm a magic user currently I'm wondering if the same holds true for magic attacks performed while sneaking.

Do any ranged attacks like bows or magic deal extra damage while sneaking? Is there any difference here between archery and magic?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You'll do double damage if you sneak attack with a bow, just like you would with a melee weapon. If you have the Path of Stealth skill *Deadly Aim*, sneak attacks with bows deal three times as much damage.

There is no bonus for sneak attacking with magic.

Comment: Max damage? My bow sneak attacks have been doing x2 damage.

Comment: @Arkive You're right: I should've made it clearer what I meant by that. It is double damage for a sneak attack, triple damage with Deadly Aim